# activate button after another button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three button are after clicking on one button,second has to access the click and then the third .when i  click on the third button it should not work

```
<input type="button" value="button" id="one" onclick="show()" action="">
<input type="button" value="button" id="two" onclick="show1()">
<input type="action" value="button" id="three">

<script>
function show{ 
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: what exactly you want's to do..

Comment: I have Three button on the same page with three different actions .k

Comment: when first button is clicked .he can able to click second button .then third.when he clicked the second button directly it will not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially disable second and third button using :

```
<input type="button" value="button" id="two" onclick="show1()" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="action" value="button" id="three" disabled="disabled"/>
```

And Use this code :

```
function show()
{
    document.getElementById('two').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
// And Same For Second Button Click
function show1()
{
    document.getElementById('three').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery would be better here:

```
$('#one').click(function () { // on a click on the button with id 'one'
  $('#two').trigger('click');// trigger the click on second, and go on 
}
```

Using this method you can trigger events on other elements using an event on a particular element!

Comment: i dont want the auto click the second .user has to click the second one

Comment: after clicking first button only they can go to second button

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    function show(){ 
$('#button1').attr('disabled',false);
$('#button2').attr('disabled',false);

    }
    function show1(){
$('#button2').attr('disabled',false);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: i am not asking the auto click of one by one button .user have to click one button after other

Comment: after clicking one button only they can go to second button

Comment: @user3383271 where? I have given you basic idea. You can take care of rest I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery to bind an event to the click.
and there do what you want:

```
$('#ButtonID').bind('click',function(){
   $('#ButtonID2').show(); 
    //or
   $('#ButtonID1').removeAttr('disabled');//if you want it be shown but not enabled
});
```

this is for disableing the buttons:

```
 $('#ButtonID').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: i am not asking the auto click of one by one button .user have to click one button after other .after clicking first button only they can go to second button

Comment: you need to show from start all buttons? if not you can use Jquery hide() and show() in each click show the next button.

Comment: k can you show me how .hide two buttons when the page is opened and one will there .click on that one and show other two

Comment: k can you show me how .hide two buttons when the page is opened and one will there .click on that one and show other two

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
$("input").click(function(){
 $("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
$(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Udxyb/438/)